# Java Socket Issue: Packets Are Merged At The Receiver Side

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm having a socket problem. This problem occurs when I'm running the server and client on the same PC i.e. using "localhost" parameter. But problem is not seen when different PCs are being used. 
Client sends a file with these codes:

```
output_local.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
output_local.flush();
```

And after that in another method I'm sending a command with these:

```
outputStream.write(string);
outputStream.flush();
```

Server appends the command to the end of the file. So it thinks it hasn't received the command from the client yet. do you have an idea what might causing this problem? How can I solve the defect? below is the file receive method at the server:

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytesReceived = input.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("exception occured");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("received:" + bytesReceived);
        try {
            /* Write to the file */
            wr.write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        total_byte = total_byte + bytesReceived;
        if (total_byte >= filesizeInt) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want message-like support, you need a create a protocol to clarify what you're going to send and receive.

In TCP, you can't rely on separate "packets" being received separately (e.g., sending 4 chunks of 10 bytes may be received as 1 chunk of 40, or of 2 chunks of 20, or one chunk of 39 and one chunk of 1).  TCP guarantees in order delivery, but not any particular 'packetization' of your data.

So, for example, if you're sending a string you need to first send the string length then its bytes.  The logic in pseudocode would be something like:

**Client:**

1. Send the command indicator
2. Send the payload length
3. Send the payload

**Server:**

1. Read the command indicator
2. Read the payload length
3. Loop reading payload until the complete length has been read

Answer (score 5):

The defect is that you're treating a *stream-based* protocol (TCP) as if it were a message-oriented protocol. It's not. You should *assume* that this can happen.

If you need to break your stream into individual messages, you should use either delimiters or (preferably IMO) a length prefix for each message. You should also then anticipate that *any* read you issue may not receive as much data as you've asked for - in other words, not only can messages be combined if you're not careful, but they can easily be split.

I mentioned that I prefer length-prefixing to delimiters. Pros and cons:

- The benefit of using a message delimiter is that you don't need to know the message size before you start sending.
- The benefits of using a length prefix are:

  - The code for reading the message doesn't need to care about the data within the message *at all* - it only needs to know how long it is. You read the message length, you read the message data (looping round until you've read it all) and then you pass the message on for process. Simple.
  - You don't need to worry about "escaping" the delimiter if you want it to appear within a normal message.

Answer (score 3):

As TCP is a stream oriented connection, this behaviour is normal if the writer writes faster than the reader reads, or than the TCP stack sends packets.

You should add a separator to separate the parts of the streams, e.g. by using a length field for sub packets, or by using separators such as newline (`\n`, char code 10).

Another option could be to use UDP (or even SCTP), but that depends on the task to be fulfilled.